# Labels in peak in chart (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, charts

I have the graph (from CSV), and I would like to add some label in peak:

[image: This graph I have]

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={Time}, ylabel={[a.u]},
                                width=15cm,
                                height=7cm,
                                xmin=1549.5,   xmax=1551.1,
                                ymin=-75,  ymax=-15,
                                legend pos=south west, grid=major,]
            \addplot[coordinate, color=blue] table[x=x,y=y] from {graphs/OSA123.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The txt file is [here](https://pastebin.com/WHZ5HhsT).

I would like to obtain this:
[image: I would like to add the labels into graph]

Thank you very much for you time!

Answer (score 2):

Just add two nodes at the top of peaks:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={Time}, ylabel={[a.u]},
                                width=15cm,
                                height=7cm,
                                xmin=1549.5,   xmax=1551.1,
                                ymin=-75,  ymax=-15,
                                legend pos=south west, grid=major,]
            \addplot[coordinate, color=blue] table[x=x,y=y] from {graphs/OSA123.txt};
            \node[above] at (1550.1,-33) {Data (video)};
            \node[above] at (1550.9,-33) {Data (voice)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much but I always get the errors:
Dimension too large!

Comment: @Thomas I need to see your full code. Perhaps you need to add in preamble `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`

Comment: My complete code is as follows:
https://pastebin.com/Jvcp0tcc

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: @Thomas  Did you still get an error with `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`? Or try to use `axis cs:` in `\node[above] at (axis cs:1550.1,-33) {Data (video)};`

Comment: axis cs: solves my issue. Thank you very much for fast answer and nice cooperation.